# Saving datetime on meteor server issue

Tags: javascript, meteor, galaxy

I have an app that works perfectly on my local laptop :

I just want to save a new event for a calendar app, so I do this with a Meteor method on server side :

```
var startAt = moment(startString, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toDate();
var endAt = moment(endString, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toDate();
```

and then I create the object to save in the db :

```
var event = _.extend(_.pick(eventAttributes,
  "calendarId",
  "patientId",
  "tagId",
  "recurrent",
  "emailConfirmation"
), {
  status: "pending",
  startAt: startAt,
  endAt: endAt,
  cloneEvent: false,
  recurrencies: recurrencies,
  createdBy: user._id,
  submitted: new Date().getTime()
});
```

I use Meteor Galaxy and Compose (located in US, I'm working from France), my issue is when I save the event on the server I have a shift of 2 hours from the start date I created : eg : I entered 8:15 for the time and it saved at 10:15 :

```
{startAt: ISODate("2016-06-01T10:15:00Z"), endAt: ISODate("2016-06-01T11:00:00Z" }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried doing it through moment-timezone?

Comment: I did but same result. But if I use moment on client side and then send the date to server method it works. I would understand why this behaviour...